# Relative Thom isomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, vector-bundles, group-actions, principal-bundles

Let $\tilde{X}$ be a space with an action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_k$ and define $X:=\tilde{X}/\mathfrak{S}_k$ to be the quotient. On the other hand, $\mathfrak{S}_k$ acts on $(\mathbb{R}^2)^k$ by interchanging coordinate blocks of size 2 (I just included the $2$ in order to get something orientable at the end). We can consider the map $p\colon E:=\tilde{X}\times_{\mathfrak{S}_k}(\mathbb{R}^2)^k\to X$.

If the original action was free, then $p$ would be a $2k$-dimensional orientable vector bundle and we would have a Thom isomorphism $H^*(X)\to \tilde{H}^{*+2k}\mathrm{Th}(E)$. However, I think it is not hard to see that something slightly more general is true: Let $A\subseteq X$ be a cofibration. We can define the relative Thom space
$$\mathrm{Th}_A(E):=\mathbb{D}E/(\mathbb{S}E\cup \mathbb{D}E|_A),$$
where $\mathbb{D}E$ and $\mathbb{S}E$ are the induced disc and sphere bundles, and we should be able to see that there is a “relative” Thom class inducing an isomorphism
$$H^*(X,A)\to H^{*+2k}(\mathbb{D}E,\mathbb{S}E\cup \mathbb{D}E|_A)=\tilde{H}^{*+2k}\mathrm{Th}_A(E)$$

If $E\to X$ is in total a vector bundle, then should be possible to show by standard methods, but now the subtlety comes: I now only want to assume that $E|_{X\smallsetminus A}\to X\smallsetminus A$ is an honest bundle, i.e. $\mathfrak{S}_k$ should be allowed to act non-freely on $p^{-1}(A)$.

Still, we can speak of induced disc and sphere bundles and define this relative Thom space $\mathrm{Th}_A(E)$. It somehow feels that it should still be possible to give such an isomorphism; since, intuitively, the “bad part” is quotiented out anyway. However, I am not sure how to make this isomorphism precise.

Comment: Replace $\tilde X$ with $\tilde X\times E{\frak S}_k$. Now you have a vector bundle $\tilde X\times E{\frak S}_k \times_{{\frak S}_k} (\mathbb R^2)^k\to (\tilde X\times E{\frak S}_k)/_{{\frak S}_k}$ and a corresponding Thom isomorphism. Similarly if you replace $X$ with $A$. By the five-lemma you get a relative Thom isomorphism like you describe, with homotopy quotients replacing quotients. OTOH, the map $(X\times E{\frak S}_k)_{{\frak S}_k}/(A\times E{\frak S}_k)_{{\frak S}_k}\xrightarrow{\simeq} X/A_{{\frak S}_k}$ is an equivalence, and there is a similar equivalence of relative Thom spaces.